# cakephp implement modal window for edit

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I have a simple application that displays a list of records and I want to implement a bootstrap modal window for editing the records.  I'm new to php but am trying cakePHP because I prefer MVC.

I have a dropdown on each table row that after selecting, I want to open the modal, make changes, and save.  Currently, I am implementing a link to call the url to get the data async and update a div with the response.  I have this working but the data is being cached so it displays the data from the first record displayed even after selecting a new record.  I'm sure I can find a way to clear it but it makes me question how I went about implementing the modal window.

The list view has the following:

```
<li>
          <?php              
          echo $this->Js->link("Edit settings","/units/edit/".$unit['Unit']['id'] ,
                  array('update' => '#editModal',
                      'htmlAttributes' => array(
                          'data-toggle' => 'modal',
                          'data-target' => '#editModal'
                      )));
          ?>
        </li>
```

Controller:

```
if (!$this->Unit->exists($id)) {
  throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid unit'));
}
if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
  if ($this->Unit->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The unit has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
  } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The unit could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
  }
} else {
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $this->render('edit', 'ajax');
  }
}
```

edit view:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
```

×
      Modal title

```
<?php

  echo $this->Form->create('Unit');
  echo $this->Form->input('name', array('class' => 'form-control', 'div' => 'form-group', 'disabled' => 'disabled'));
  echo $this->Form->input('internet_class_id', array('class' => 'form-control', 'div' => 'form-group'));
  $offOn = array(0 => 'Off', 1 => 'On');
  echo $this->Form->input('water_setting_id', array('options' => $offOn, 'default' => 0,
      'class' => 'form-control', 'div' => 'form-group'));
  $amenitySettings = array(0 => 'Deny', 1 => 'Allow');
  echo $this->Form->input('amenity_setting_id', array('options' => $amenitySettings, 'default' => 0,
      'class' => 'form-control', 'div' => 'form-group'));
  echo $this->Form->input('cable_setting_id', array('options' => $offOn, 'default' => 0,
      'class' => 'form-control', 'div' => 'form-group'));
  echo $this->Form->hidden('id');
  echo $this->Form->hidden('building_id');
  echo $this->Form->button('Save', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary'));
  echo $this->Form->end();
  ?>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

This may be the wrong way to implement so I am open to suggestions.  Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing.  This solution is pieced together from other answers found on stackoverflow:

In the controller, I added a simple check for an ajax request and if so, rendered the view with the empty ajax layout:

```
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $this->render('edit', 'ajax');
  }
```

I then added this jquery to the view:

```
$("a[data-target=#flexModal]").click(function(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var target = $(this).attr("href");
// load the url and show modal on success
$("#flexModal .modal-body").load(target, function() {
  $("#flexModal").modal("show");
});
});
```

Using this, each time I click the manage button for the model I am working with, an ajax call is made and the results are added to the body of the modal.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your UnitsController beforeFilter callback method:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
            parent::beforeFilter();
            if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
                    $this->response->disableCache();
            }
}
```

This checks that the request was made via Ajax using the is() method of the CakeRequest object and passing the ajax value. If this is the case, we'll disable caching, as we always want to serve our Ajax calls fresh. This should take care of the issue you had where "the data is being cached so it displays the data from the first record displayed even after selecting a new record."